# Does the following Diffie-Hellman problem hold in bilinear groups $G\times G \rightarrow G_T$

Tags: diffie-hellman, pairings, hardness-assumptions

For every PPT distinguisher A there exists a negligible function $neg(·)$ such that for all $\lambda$

$|\Pr[A(1^\lambda, g,g_1^a,g_1^b,g_1^{ab}) = 1] - \Pr[A(1^\lambda, g,g_1^a,g_1^b,g_1^z) = 1]| \leq \textsf{negl}(\lambda)$

where $g$ is a generator of group $G$ of order $p$ where $p$ is a prime of length approximately $\lambda$, $g_1 = g^r \in G$, and $r,a,b,z$ are randomly chosen from $Z_p$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose we modify the problem so that $r, a, b, z$ are selected uniformly randomly from the interval $[1, p-1]$; how do the probability distributions of $(g^{ra}, g^{rb}, g^{rab})$ and $(g^{ra}, g^{rb}, g^{rz})$ compare?

Hint: if we actually select $r, a, b, z$ from $\mathbb{Z}_p$, what is the probability that at least one of them are selected outside the interval $[1, p-1]$?  Can you show that this probability is negligible?